# How to create and use an optional parameter in Vue Router?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I need to route to a certain component in two ways - one with a param, one without. I have searched for optional params and somehow can't find much info.

So my route:

```
{
    path: '/offers/:member',
    component: Offers,
    name: 'offers',
    props: true,
    meta: {
        guest: false,
        needsAuth: true
    }
},
```

When I call it with the param programmatically, all is fine

```
this.$router.push({ path: /offers/1234 });
```

However I also need to call it via nav like this

```
<router-link to="/offers">Offers</router-link>
```

The `offers` component accepts the prop

```
props: ['member'],
```

And component used as such

```
<Offers :offers="data" :member="member"></Offers>
```

Now the ugly way I've managed to get it working is duplicating the route and making one of them not take props:

```
{
    path: '/offers',
    component: Offers,
    name: 'offers',
    props: false,
    meta: {
        guest: false,
        needsAuth: true
    }
},
```

It actually works, but i'm not happy with it - also in dev mode vuejs is warning me `[vue-router] Duplicate named routes definition: { name: "offers", path: "/offers" }`

Surely there's a way to do optional param in the component call `:member="member"` ?

Answer (score 507, accepted):

Just adding a question mark `?` will make it optional.

```
{
    path: '/offers/:member?',
    ...
},
```

It works for Vue Router 2.0 onward.

Source: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/235#issuecomment-245447122

Comment: Would love if this was in the guide!

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Wish this was clearly mentioned in the guide.

Comment: This also works if the param is not at the end. ```path: /:lang?/home``` will be executed for ```/home``` as well as ```/es/home```. (With Vue-Router 4.0.3, i havent tried other versions.)

Comment: This is a great answer, especially since it's nowhere to be found in vue routers documentation.

Comment: Fantastic, I still can't find this in the officel Vue router docs.

Comment: Looks like they documented it but have it hidden at the bottom of Route Matching Patterns [Optional Params](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/route-matching-syntax.html#optional-parameters) Worth mentioning, If you want to explicitly list both the routes to make it clear you can do so as long as `/:foo?` comes after `/` . Order matters to keep from getting unmatched warning

Answer (score 6):

For advanced routes matching patterns [the manual says](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#advanced-matching-patterns) :

> vue-router uses **path-to-regexp** as its path matching engine, so it supports many advanced matching patterns such as optional dynamic segments, zero or more / one or more requirements, and even custom regex patterns. Check out its documentation for these advanced patterns, and this example of using them in vue-router.

path-to-regexp page/manual => https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0#parameters

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, you can also send different params, from where you call your route.

```
<router-link
  :to="{
    name: 'ComponentName',
    params: { member: {}, otherParams: {} }
  }"
/>
```