# Is it posible having an optional vue route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

In my vue application I need an optional router like this

```
#/profile/(:user/)?task/current-task
```

Here I want user will be optional. if user not exit then I want to show current login user task.
I know `#/profile/(:user/)?` it possible. But having children after an optional params not working for me.
any suggestion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optional param in vuejs router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824660/optional-param-in-vuejs-router)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible

You can define `#/profile/:user?/task/current-task`

Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/29jvk913/

More nested params

http://jsfiddle.net/y3kbovhy/

Comment: Right now I have such problem when my route end on optional params it removes from when you route in search for example ( /root/:id?) this works. But when you add path after optional params it doesn't remove anything (/root/:id?/example). Can you explain why this happening? How to make always removable?