# Vue router dynamic id and name in child route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a routing:

```
{
    path: '/user',
    name: 'user',
    component: () => import('@/views/users/Users.vue'),
    children: [
        {
        path: '/:id/:username?',
        name: 'userData',
        component: () => import('@/components/users/User.vue'),
        },
    ],
},
```

My setting router:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
   mode: 'history',
   base: process.env.BASE_URL,
   scrollBehavior: () => ({ y: 0 }),
});
```

I have a problem with child element in route. When I go to the site `http://localhost:8080/user` I see list with all user from databse. But when i go to the site: `http://localhost:8080/user/1/john` vue loads view again with all user (view `Users.vue`), here I need load component with data of one user (component `User.vue`). Parameter `username` is optinal.

Comment: Have you checked this?

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/route-matching/app.js

From `http://localhost:8080/user/1/john` it goes with `/:id/:username` since you didn't assign a component for that route, it inherits parent component `Users.vue`

Comment: You must create two routers without parent/children.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824660/optional-param-in-vuejs-router

Adding this existing thread as another reference.

Comment: Try removing the first slash char in `/:id/:username?`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is you are adding `/` prefixed children route. The documentation clearly says that

> Note that nested paths that start with / will be treated as a root path. This allows you to leverage the component nesting without having to use a nested URL.

You should rewrite the children route as given and it should work.

```js
children: [
    {
        path: ':id/:username?',
        name: 'userData',
        component: () => import('@/components/users/User.vue'),
    },
],
```

You can only add `/` to the root routes. any route that is written starting with slash will be treated as root route in vue-router.