# How to use VueJS router properly?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm doing multilingual functionality based on locale params and this is the route I've configured:

```js
  const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
    
  },
  {
    path: '/:locale',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/about:locale',
    name: 'About',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/recruit/:locale',
    name: 'Recruit',
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Recruit" */ '../views/Recruit/index.vue'),
  },
{
    path: '/detail/:id/:locale',
    name: 'Detail',
    // props: (route) => ({ id: route.params.id }),
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Detail" */ '../views/Recruit/Detail.vue'),
  },
]
```

And it throws an error that if when on home page and params locale is empty valid(/) instead of /en or /fr,... then when I redirect to another page the URL bar is completely blank and there is no any path.
This is my redirected router-link:

```js
 <router-link
                class="nav-link rttr"
                :to="{ name: 'Recruit'}"
              >
                Recruit
</router-link>
```

So is there a way when I redirect and the router params has no value (/) the path in the URL bar will still display correctly or not?

Comment: try doing this `:to="{ name: 'Recruit', params: { locale: ''}}"`

Comment: I tried however when I click go to the recruit page it's still just a blank url instead of /recruit

Comment: still getting the same error?

Comment: It doesn't give an error, it just doesn't go to the destination I want, when I switch the page it will still go to the Recruit page but on the URL bar there is no change.

Comment: So now its going to that recruit page, but the url alone is not showing as expected! right??

Comment: Yes, because this is a recruitment page, I need to get the page link to send it to the candidate but now it is not showing the link if the locale has nothing, and if the locale has a value like /en /fr, the link is still there. display.

Comment: how about `details` page, is it showing up in the url even if you don't send the id?

Comment: yes if there is no id it doesn't show....

Comment: I was wrong, it still shows even though the URL is empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47824660/optional-param-in-vuejs-router

Comment: ohhh thanks. it works fine with recruit page, but i have trouble with detail page, i set router link as: :to="{ name: 'Detail', params: { id: item.id } }" and stay router is
path:'/detail/:id/:locale?',
name: 'Detail', on the detail page it always gets blank value even though I changed the locale params before

Comment: guess for details page, the id won't be optional

Comment: How do I need to handle it? thank you very much